# Software for syncing my Wattpad reading progress on Goodreads?

Tags: gratis, android, web-apps, ebooks

Are there any software which can sync my [Wattpad](https://www.wattpad.com/home) reading progress on [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/)?

As Wattpad calculates the estimated time left for completing the book; as a measure of reading progress, I can't update it on Goodreads manually, if not direct syncing, as there is no way to know the progress in terms of pages and %age.

Would be very nice if it is compatible both on the web and has a mobile app (android)too.

I also own a Kindle, so if possible then please suggest if it is possible to sync the data through it.

Would prefer a gratis software as both Goodreads and Wattpad are free. So, having a paid app for syncing data between them would be senseless IMO.